# Sending data from jsp to struts2 action class using Jquery Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I need to pass the form data from jsp to struts2 using jquery Ajax and receive back a JSON data from Struts2 action class. 
I have given the code below. When i am passing the AJAX data ,

```
url:'search.action?searchText='+ $('searchValue').value+'&environment='+$('environmentSelect').value
```

"undefined" is getting passed instead of the orijinal value from jsp to the action class.

My JSP

```
 <div id="tab0">
                <s:form action="search" method="post">

                    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Environment:</td>
                            <td><select id="environmentSelect" name="environment">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Search Value:</td>
                            <td><input id="searchValue" name="searchText" type="text" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><button id="searchButton">Search</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </s:form>
            </div>
```

My Ajax function is:

```
$("#searchButton").on("click",function(){

            console.log("Inside Ajax call = "+  $('#tab0'));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'search.action?searchText='+ $('searchValue').value+'&environment='+$('environmentSelect').value,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(stringify(data));
                        s=data....
                        }

                    document.getElementById('displayLog').innerHTML=s;
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Struts.xml:

```
 <struts>
        <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
            value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
            value="ApplicationResources" />
        <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/> 
        <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />

        <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
            <action name="search" class="com.SearchAction" method="execute">
                <result name="success">/jsp/dummy.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/jsp/search.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>  

    </struts>
```

Action Class:

```
public class SearchAction extends ActionSupport {

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  private String environment;
  private String searchText;


    public String getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(String environment) {
        System.out.println("environment in setter new = "+ environment);
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public String getSearchText() {
        return searchText;
    }

    public void setSearchText(String searchText) {
        System.out.println("searchText in setter = "+ searchText);
        this.searchText = searchText;
    }



  public String execute() {

    Map map1 = new Map();
    if(environment !=null && searchText != null){
        map1= getMap(environment,searchText);
        return success;
    }
    else{
        return "error";
    }
}
}
```

I did not incorporate the JSON logic yet. Struck with the "undefined" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` function as below

```
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url:'search.action?searchText='+ $("#searchValue").val()+'&environment='+$("#environmentSelect").val(),
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
             console.log(stringify(data));
        }});
```

The other way is to

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'search.action?searchText='+ document.getElementById('searchValue').value  +'&environment='+document.getElementById('environmentSelect').value,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
          console.log(stringify(data));
          }});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you for answer. Getting the form value by using document.getElementId works fine but getting the data using $("#searchValue").val() still gives undefined. I will look in to it. Anyway Thank you !

Comment: it shouldn't give you undefined, if you have jquery.min.js in your script

Comment: I got that there was a typo. Thank you ! Do you have any idea how to receive the JSON data in to a jsp page? If you see in my struts.xml if it is success i am directing it to dummy.jsp. That page contains only the `<s:property value="map1"/>` which i am setting it in my action class. Now i need to display that in the dummy.jsp. How to do that?

Comment: You are expecting a json value from server. so, you need to create the json string and return to the client. Check this link http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/

Comment: @Keerthivasan: What if you have many elements in the form and we want to pass all those parameter as a bean instead of passing each and every parameter separately, like we use model in struts2.Could you please advise if that can be done

Answer (score 1):

Very Important (If you want to transfer data from Action Class to JQuery) without these 3 jar files you can not pass variable from Action Class to JQuery.

- json-simple-1.1.jar
- struts2-json-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar

Struts.xml

```
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
   <action name="action_name" class="com.ActionClass" method="execute">
       <result type="json">
           <param name="root">jsonData</param>
       </result>
   </action>
</package>
```